# Adding multiple objects with One to zero/one relation Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

I have two classes: `Transaction` and `PosReference`.

- Each `transaction` may have a `posReference` associated with it
- Each `posReference` must have a `transaction`

Code:

```
public class Transaction : Entity 
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public virtual PosReference PosReference { get; set; }
}

public class PosReference : Entity 
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
    public PosReference(Transaction transaction){
         Id = transaction.Id;
    }
}
```

and mapping is written as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>()     // one-to-one or zero relation
         .HasOptional(m => m.PosReference)
         .WithRequired(t => t.Transaction);
```

If I try to add one `transaction` and `posReference` pair at a time and then save the context in the database, everything works fine.

But if I try to add multiple `transaction-posReference` pairs, this exception is thrown:

> Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Transaction_PosReference_Target' of the relationship 'Data.Models.Transaction_PosReference' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

Is it possible to add multiple (one to zero/one) pairs? how should I change my model or mapping to achieve this?

---

EDIT:

Simplified code for two services are as below:

```
public class TransactionServices {
    private readonly IRepositoryAsync<Transaction> _repository;
    public TransactionServices(IRepositoryAsync<Transaction> repository){
        _repository = repository;
    }
    public Transaction Add(){
        var transaction = new Transaction();
        _repository.Insert(transaction);
        return transaction;
    }
}
public class PosReferenceServices {
    private readonly IRepositoryAsync<PosReference> _repository;
    public PosReferenceServices(IRepositoryAsync<PosReference> repository){
        _repository = repository;
    }
    public PosReference Add(Transaction transaction){
        var posReference = new PosReference(Transaction transaction){
            Transaction = transaction
        };
        _repository.Insert(posReference);
        return posReference;
    }
}
```

Repository objects are configured in UnityConfig as below:

```
.RegisterType<IRepositoryAsync<Transaction>, Repository<Transaction>>()
.RegisterType<IRepositoryAsync<PosReference>, Repository<PosReference>>()
```

And below is the function in which objects are added:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AddTransactions(List<PosTransaction> newTransactionList){
    foreach (var posTransactionInfo in newTransactionList){
        // I have omitted some unrelated parameters from PosReference to make code cleaner and to the point
        var transaction = _transactionServices.Add();
        var posReference = _posReferenceServices.Add(transaction);
        // other posReference params would be set according to data in posTransactionInfo 
    }
    await _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Request.CreateResponse(Message.PaywandOk());
}
```

---

EDIT 2:
`Insert` function on both entities does the following:

```
private readonly IDataContextAsync _context;
private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;
private readonly IUnitOfWorkAsync _unitOfWork;

public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
{
    entity.ObjectState = ObjectState.Added;
    _dbSet.Attach(entity);
    _context.SyncObjectState(entity);         
}
```

Comment: Well, **SHOW US** how you're attempting to add multiple pairs to the database! Remember: we can't read your screen and source code - nor your mind - you need to **SHOW US!**

Comment: @marc_s sorry, Iv'e edited my question. couldn't paste the whole code because it'll be too long to read. please tell me if I should add other parts too

Comment: Well, what does the `_repository.Insert()` call do in detail? And your sample code really isn't showing when you're trying to add **multiple** pairs of data - that's the code we need to see in order to be able to help ....

Comment: `_repository.Insert()` does the following:
`public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
{
    entity.ObjectState = ObjectState.Added;
    _dbSet.Attach(entity);
    _context.SyncObjectState(entity);         
}` and the part I've tried to add multiple pairs of data is in the `for` loop in `AddTransactions` function.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: @marc_s updated the question

Comment: Remove `_dbSet.Attach(entity);` from the `Insert` method.

Comment: @GertArnold It's working, thanks. please write an answer so that I can accept it. I thought I should use one of `_dbSet.Attach(entity);` or `_dbSet.Add(entity);` to add a new record to database, I'd really appreciate it if you could explain a little about how entity is added without using neither of these two instructions in your answer.